# Adjusting grid from desktop to mobile using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to take content that is laid out with desktop as the priority, and re-flow it for mobile based on that clients wishes, but I'm not able to completely get the elements to fit.  Here's the layout on desktop:

```
+----+----+
| 1  | 2  |
|    |    |
+---------+
| 3  | 4  |
|    | 5  |
+---------+
```

Elements 4 and 5 are in a wrapping div together because they're each half the height of element 3.  Desktop is the priority, so it's be developed with that in mind. Here's what I want to accomplish for mobile:

```
+----+----+
|    1    |
|         |
+---------+
| 4  | 2  |
| 5  | 3  |
+---------+
```

Using flexbox I've managed to get all the elements repositioned except 2. It just wraps to the next line.

I realize it's not ideal, but is there any way to get the 2nd element to line up under the 3rd to make a 1x2 grid?

Here's the code that I've gotten close with:

```
#wrapper { display: -webkit-flex; flex-wrap: wrap; align-content: stretch; }

#1 { order: 1; flex: 1 100%; }
#2 { order: 3; flex: 3 50%; }
#3 { order: 4; flex: 4 50%;  }
#4&5wrapper { order: 2; flex: 2 50%; }
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Possibly but you may need extra wrappers. Frankly though, I doubt it.

Comment: Please reproduce what you've accomplished so far using jsFiddle.net, CodePen.io, and/or the snippet feature.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of your code, e.g. on JSFiddle? It's really hard to reproduce what's going on...

Comment: I'm gonna a say the answer is..."NO". - You'd need to wrap 4/5 & 2/3 in separate wrappers in order to stack them inside their individual containers. 
- The stacking is simple enough either via `flex-wrap:wrap` or `flex-direction:column` **BUT** once you have put 2/3 in a wrapper you then can't force that element into a zig-zag shape which would be required by the desktop layout.

Comment: Yeah..I'm gonna say my answer is ... **'NO'** I won't bother helping you. I took the initiative to make a demo with what little info you gave. I have just a couple of questions and it was ready to go. If we took the time, maybe you should meet us halfway.

Comment: @RenevanderLende or Shaun? Why do you use 2 logons? So you can be rude on one logon and then answer your own question with the alternate logon? There's nothing wrong about answering your own question. Going through the subterfuge to do so is sad. Looks like you need to start breathing, that's how you supply oxygen to your brain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer to your question is no. Here's why:

The desktop layout is not a problem with flexbox. You simply need to wrap boxes 4 and 5 in a nested column-direction flex container, and you're done.

[image]

```
.inner-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    order: 4;
    flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 10px - 2px); /* width less margin less borders */
}
```

However, for the mobile layout, which requires boxes 2 and 3 to adjust from a row-based wrap in the outer flex container to a column-direction stack in an inner flex container (like with boxes 4 and 5), you would need to change the mark-up.

The best you can do (or at least I could do) without changing the mark-up is this:

[image]

Here's the code from the demos in case you're interested in playing with it:

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer-container">
    <span class="box box1">1</span>
    <span class="box box2">2</span>
    <span class="box box3">3</span>
    <div class="inner-container">
        <span class="box box4">4</span>
        <span class="box box5">5</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** (includes non-essential decorative styles)

```
body { display: flex; align-items: flex-start; }

.outer-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 6px 0;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 250px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.inner-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    order: 4;
    flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 10px - 2px); /* width less margin less borders */
}

.box1 { flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 10px - 2px); order: 1; }
.box2 { flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 10px - 2px); order: 2; }
.box3 { flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 10px - 2px); order: 3; }
.box4 { flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 10px - 2px); width: 100%; }
.box5 { flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 10px - 2px); width: 100%; }

div.outer-container:last-of-type > .box1 { flex: 0 1 calc(100% - 10px - 2px); order: 1;}
div.outer-container:last-of-type > .inner-container { order: 2; margin-right: 10px; }
div.outer-container:last-of-type > .box2 { order: 3; }
div.outer-container:last-of-type > .box3 { order: 4; flex: 1 1 100%; }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dLgjuyw6/1/ (Firefox)

EDIT: Just noticed that demo code (as pictured) works in FF but not Chrome. As this demo is solely for illustration purposes and non-essential to the answer I'm not pursuing browser compatibility.

Comment: While filled with nice trickery it is too complicated for this question

Comment: @RenevanderLende, I don't think so, Rene. Your solution does not answer the question. I'll provide details in your answer.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried a lot of different approaches and wasn't able to get it, so I just wanted to see if anyone smarter than me was able to tell me if I was missing something.  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Not really about smarts. Flexbox just isn't designed to do everything. In fact, it's not even really a grid system. Which is why the W3C is developing the [**grid layout module**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/).

Answer (score 1):

I realise you've already accepted no as an answer but I'm not yet convinced.

I think the following solution answers the question. Note that I've chosen the flex-bases(?) so that their sum is 100% but you don't have to do that. That way there is some leeway to adjust to the content.

To see what happens watch the solution in full screen and make your browser window narrow (< 600 px). Or watch it on [codepen](http://codepen.io/woestijnrog/full/xwaPdW/).

```css
    #one {background: lightblue;}   
    #two {background: skyblue;}   
    #three {background: blue;}   
    #four {background: aqua;}   
    #five {background: lime;}   
    div {flex: 1;}
    #wrapper {width: 100%; height: 95vh; border: 1px solid;}
    @media (min-width:600px){
        #wrapper {
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column wrap;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        div {width: 50%;}
        #one{
            order: 1;
            flex-basis: 66%;
        }
        #two{
            order: 2;
            flex-basis: 66%;
        }
        #three{
            order: 1;
            flex-basis: 34%;
        }
        #four{
            order: 2;
            flex-basis: 17%;
        }
        #five{
            order: 2;
            flex-basis: 17%
        }
    }
    @media (max-width:599px){
        #wrapper {
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #one{
            order: 1;
            flex-basis: 100%;
            min-height: 40vh;
        }
        #two{
            order: 3;
            flex-basis: 50%;
        }
        #three{
            order: 5;
            flex-basis: 50%;
        }
        #four{
            order: 2;
            flex-basis: 50%;
        }
        #five{
            order: 4;
            flex-basis: 50%
        }
        
    }
```

```html
 <div id='wrapper'>
        <div id='one'>1</div>
        <div id='two'>2</div>
        <div id='three'>3</div>
        <div id='four'>4</div>
        <div id='five'>5</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**- UPDATED -**

The answer is **YES**,

...but with some trickery and maybe not the flexing you might like with 2 flex wrappers side-by-side. Splitting the problem in two, a regular flex container (1&2&3) and some relative positioning of a second (4&5) you will get the required layout.

I am not sure this is the best to do or even the answer you wanted, but maybe it is just what you needed.

Have a look at the snippet and let me know!

```css
/* Global stuff */
html, body  { box-sizing: border-box; height: 100%; width: 100%;
              margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0 }
*, *:before,
*:after     { box-sizing: inherit }

/* Solution */
#w1         { display: flex; 
              flex-flow: column wrap;    /* vertical arrangement */
              align-items: flex-end;     /* forces 2&3 to lower right */
              with: 100%; height: 100% } /* full screen */

#i1         { width: 100%; height: 50% } /* full width, half height of #w1 */
#i2,#i3     { width:  50%; height: 25% } /* half width, half height of #w1 */

#w2         { display: flex; flex-direction: column;/* stay unchanged */
              position: absolute; top: 50%;         /* nasty, but works */
              width:  50%; height: 50% }            /* stay unchanged */

#i4,#i5     { width: 100%; height: 50%  }           /* stay unchanged */

#i1::before { content: 'mobile '}

@media all and (min-width: 720px) {

    #i1::before { content: 'desktop '}

    /* become equal in size */
    #i1,#i2,#i3 { width:  50%; height: 50% }    /* half width, half height of #w1 */

    #w1         { flex-flow: row wrap;          /* horizontal arrangement */
                  justify: content: flex-start }/* forces 1&2&3 to upper left */   
    #w2         { right: 0 }                    /* reposition, nasty, but works */
}      

/* Demo */
#w1 *, #w2 *    { text-align: center; font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold;
                  background: #f0f0f0; border: 2px solid black }
```

```html
<div id="w1">
    <div id="i1">1</div>
    <div id="i2">2</div>
    <div id="i3">3</div>
</div>

<div id="w2">
    <div id="i4">4</div>
    <div id="i5">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution does not address the problem. On desktop, boxes 4 and 5 must be half-height, so they both equal the height of 3. In other words, box 3, and boxes 4 and 5, should be on the same row. In your answer, that is not the case.

Comment: You said *hold on*. So I'm waiting to see your revised answer. The down vote is not mine.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified with a fiddle to better display my dilemma. Frustration led me to ignore what I should have done to get the info across.  Thanks for the info though!

Comment: @Michael_B, no worries, I deserved it anyway (probably by zer00ne). And my wife had dinner ready. She's been looking cross-eyed at me since, as my bleak, empty and puzzled face scared her ( a bit ;-p ). Anyway, this question is still making me, you know, hair-pulling. Feeling like a pitbull right now.